# How to replace space by __

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line

I have a file containing space for example like this:

```
ACTTTTTTTTGSGSGSGSG  TTT
RTATATTATRSSTSTSTST  HHH
```

I want to eliminate the space and get the result:

```
ACTTTTTTTTGSGSGSGSG__TTT
RTATATTATRSSTSTSTST__HHH
```

Comment: Do you have _only_ these kinds of lines in your file, or does the file contain any other type of data (like headers)?  Will there only be one replacement per line, and could the holes be anywhere?  Are the holes always two spaces, or should single-space holes (or 3 space or longer) also be filled?

Comment: Welcome! There are *two* blank spaces, right? Or can be any number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`,  assuming that the purpose is to replace each blank space with an underscore (`_`), for all blanks spaces in the lines

```
sed 's/ /_/g' file
```

Tests

```
$ cat file
ACTTTTTTTTGSGSGSGSG  TTT
RTATATTATRSSTSTSTST  HHH

$ sed 's/ /_/g' file
ACTTTTTTTTGSGSGSGSG__TTT
RTATATTATRSSTSTSTST__HHH
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of @Paulo Tomé, assuming there can be *more* than two spaces:

```
tr -s '[[:blank:]]' < file | sed 's/[[:blank:]]/__/'
```

Assuming it's always two spaces:

```
tr '[[:blank:]]' '_' < file
```

These works even if the blanks are tabs:

Comment: `sed 's/  */__/'` or `sed -E 's/[[:blank]]+/__/'` ?

Comment: @ilkkachu You are rigth I messed with my tests

Comment: @ilkkachu the `+`  or `*` are not needed since `tr  -s` squeeshes the blanks to only one. Therefore there's no need of `-E` [[:blank:]] in `sed`. Or am I missing something?